# how can I track google plus views in my website?

Tags: javascript, google

I am trying to find how I can  track google plus clicks in  my website for tracking purposes?
Solutions not related to google analytics plse?

Comment: Are you trying to track how many users have clicked a "+1" on your site, *when* a user clicks "+1" on your site, or if a user *arrived* at your page by following a link posted at `https://plus.google.com` ..?

Answer (score 2):

Solutions also not related to Google Webmaster Tools? Because they do give insight in +1's

Answer (score 1):

I believe its possible now.
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">{parsetags:'explicit'}</script>
<g:plusone callback="scPlus"></g:plusone>
<script type="text/javascript">
    gapi.plusone.go();
    function scPlus(data) {
        if(data.state == "on") {
            // Do Stuff Here
            alert("G+ "+data.href+" +1'd "+data.state);
        } else {
            // Do Stuff Here
            alert("G+ "+data.href+" -1'd "+data.state);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google [this is not possible](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0e34b7ac4dac9f95&hl=en) as of 8/31/11 at least.

A hacky workaround would be to request the google+ iframe html and then parse the # out.